# Load nodejs module dynamically with mocked filesystem in jest unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, module, mocking, jestjs

Well I'm trying to unit test a module loading script. Part of it is of course creating mocks for the scripts. For this `mock-fs` library is used.

```
import mock = require("mock-fs");
describe("getFileConfig", function () {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        mock.restore();
    });

    it("should read and parse .js from ./config", async () => {
        const expected = {
            abc: 1,
            fun: function() {return true;}
        };
        mock({config: {"myCfg.js": "module.exports = {abc: 1, fun: function(){return true;}}"}});
        const test = require("./config/myCfg.js");
        expect(test.abc).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

I "think" this should work? - mock creates a local copy of the file systems right?

However when I test above test the following error occurs:

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/myCfg.js' from 'test/loader.test.ts'
```

So this means the module loader is *not* using the mocked filesystem? How can make it use the mocked filesystem?

Comment: `mock-fs` is made to... mock `fs`! You're not using `fs` anywhere here, you're using `require`, which is not mocked. Use [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) instead

Comment: @blex thanks but that doesn't seem to work with `ts-node` it doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: It's important to note that `mock-require` does not emulate a file system. Instead, it hijacks what that `require` would return. So, this should work: `const mock = require('mock-require'); mock('./config/myCfg.js', expected);`